# Javascript : push in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3

In calcRoute function, I fill the 'dis' array with the distance between markers and I pass it to callback function (see below).
I'm supposed to get an array with 20 values, but when I display It, I get something strange.

```
for (var i = 0; i < f.legs.length; i++) {
        routeSegment += 1;
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";

        summaryPanel.innerHTML += f.legs[i].distance.text + "<br /><br />";
        l += f.legs[i].distance.text

        dis.push(l);
        callback( dis );   

}

function callback(result) {
// code that depends on 'result'

    alert(result);

}
```

My code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agr3a07m/104/).

Comment: it's not strange at all, you are running the callback function in every iteration, I suppose you only want to call it once after the for loop finishes

Comment: Why do I get undefine among values  ?

Comment: Because you didn't assign value to `l`, so it starts with `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign `var l="";`

> Variable must be assigned with `NULL`or any value. null is used to
>   indicate an unknown value.

and consider calling your callback function outside iteration.

your code is working fine. Check out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/agr3a07m/107/)